# WatchKit: How does the dictation feature work?

Tags: watchkit, dictation

Could anybody please help me understand how does the dictation API work in WatchKit? I'm aware that we use the text input controller (presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions) to let the user dictate the text. Now I have a couple of questions:

- Can the user see the dictated text in the same controller?
- Can the user edit the text somehow?
- Can I change the look and feel of the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kavita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Can the user see the dictated text in the same controller?

When you start presentTextInputWithSuggestions, you will have a list of suggestions and a button to start dictation. If you don't add suggestions, dictation start automatically.
You will have a page for suggestion and another page for dictation. During the dictation, user sentence appears on the dictation screen. When he press "Done", you come back to your first page

- Can the user edit the text somehow?

No, the user can't edit your suggestions. However, you can save is dictation and add this text to the next suggestions for example

- Can I change the look and feel of the controller?

You can change the suggestions, the availability of emoji and dictation. However, you can't change dictation view

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications